# express-jwt middleware is not being executed in typescript decorator

Tags: typescript, express, jwt, decorator, express-jwt

I wrote my custom decorators for express.  this is the controller decorator:

```
export function controller(routePrefix: string) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    const router = AppRouter.getInstance();
    for (let key in target.prototype) {
      const routeHandler = target.prototype[key]; //getLogin
      const path = Reflect.getMetadata(
        MetadataKeys.Path,
        target.prototype,
        key
      );
      const method: Methods = Reflect.getMetadata(
        MetadataKeys.Method,
        target.prototype,
        key
      );
      const middlewares =
        Reflect.getMetadata(MetadataKeys.Middleware, target.prototype, key) ||
        [];
      if (path) {
        router[method](
          `${routePrefix}${path}`,
          ...middlewares,
          routeHandler
        );
      }
    }
  };
}
```

here is the `use` decorator:

```
export function use(middleware: RequestHandler | jwtRequestHandler) {
  return function (target: any, key: string, desc: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const middlewares =
      Reflect.getMetadata(MetadataKeys.Middleware, target, key) || [];
    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      MetadataKeys.Middleware,
      [...middlewares, middleware],
      target,
      key
    );
  };
}
```

here is the route:

@controller("/api/v1/portfolios")

```
@post("/")
  @use(checkJwt)
  @use(checkRole("admin"))
  async createPortfolio(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const portfolioData = req.body;
    console.log("portfoliodata", portfolioData);
    const userId = req.user.sub;
    const portfolio = new Portfolio(portfolioData);
    console.log("portfoliom");
    portfolio.userId = userId;
}
```

express-jwt takes the request and assigns and adds `user` to the req obj.

```
`user=req.user`
```

here is `checkJwt` middleware:

```
export const checkJwt = jwt({
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10,
    // this link is always provided by auth0 providers
    jwksUri: process.env.JWKS_URI as string,
  }),
  //   this is in the API/identifier in auth0.com
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
  //   issuer should end with "/"
  issuer: process.env.ISSUER,
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
});
```

however checkJwt is not getting executed. `checkRole` gets executed so it means my set up is correct. since checkJwt is not being executed, `req.user` is not being defined so `checkRole` catches the error. this is `checkRole` :

```
export const checkRole = (role: string) => (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  let user: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  user = req.user;
  if (user && user[process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE + "/roles"].includes(role)) {
    next();
  } else {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .send("You are not authorized to access this resource!");
  }
};
```

When i post the portfolio from client, checkRole sends this error "You are not authorized to access this resource!".

I could not figure out how to make express execute checkJwt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to the order of your decorator. [The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition) states that decorators are called top to bottom, but the results are returned bottom to top.

So your code should look like this:

```js
@post("/")
@use(checkRole("admin"))
@use(checkJwt)
async createPortfolio(req: Request, res: Response) {
   //Your code
}
```

Comment: I knew that I was missing a simple point. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Now i see why decorators are called top to bottom, but the results are bottom to top:

Calling decorators could be written like this:

```
  post(use(createPortfolio))
```

`post` calls `use`, `use` calls `createPortfolio`, that means `createPortfoli` will be on top of the call stack. So `createPortfolio` will be executed first, returns its value and then popped off the call stack